dataloader very slow with HDFf5 data
I've got a very large dataset in HDF5 format, which I cannot load in memory all at once. I'm using a custom dataset from Torch.
Here's the code:
import time
from utils import get_vocab_and_skipgrams
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import os
import h5py
import numpy as np
import torch

class CustomSkipGramDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, filename, window_size, data_dir="training_data", data_exists=True):
        self.window_size = window_size
        self.filename = filename
        self.data_exists = data_exists
        self.vocab_path = os.path.join(data_dir, "vocab.npy")
        self.hdf5_path = os.path.join(data_dir, "skipgram.h5")
        
        if not data_exists:
            get_vocab_and_skipgrams(filename, data_dir)
        
        self.vocab = np.load(self.vocab_path, allow_pickle=True).tolist()
        self.vocab_size = len(self.vocab)
        self.hf = h5py.File(self.hdf5_path, "r")
        self.dataset = self.hf["positive_skips"]
        
    def __len__(self):
        return self.dataset.shape[0]
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        
        x, y = self.dataset[index]
        return x, y

Now when I'm loading it directly like this:
with h5py.File("./training_data/skipgram.h5") as hf:
    dataset = hf["positive_skips"]
    for a in range(1,100):
        print(torch.tensor(dataset[a:100*a]))


it is indeed very fast compared to Torch custom dataset. 100x faster almost. I know I'm doing something wrong.

did you check if code works correctly with new dataset? If it works correctly then why you bother this speed.

I'm not getting why pytorch code is slow and It is so slow that it is not even fitting on 16GB GPU

This should be the same speed. Do you happen to have more code to share?

I figured I was using shuffle=True which was causing performance issue

I was using Dataloader with shuffle=True once I changed shuffle to False it works fine. It makes sense now reading from disk with shuffle would be slow.
